# CRM - Get entity name by object type code (C#)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can I get the name of an entity knowing only the objecttypecode ?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [XrmToolBox](https://github.com/MsCrmTools/XrmToolBox/releases)
2. Open Metadatabrowser [image]
3. You'll need to connect to your organizion.
4. Sort by typecode and find your entity name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you use CRM 2011 the only way is to retrieve all the entities using [RetrieveAllEntities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327860.aspx) message and then one-by-one go through entities checking objecttypecode.

In case you use CRM 2013 - you can use [Metadata Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863605.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to filter entities by objecttypecode.

Comment: I can see on the link you posted regarding CRM 2013 (Metadata Queries) that it's also available for CRM 2011. However, I don't quite understand how to use it. Any help would be appreciated